# Minecraft - keep water out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have the ships plugin on my server, and a floor of my ship is underwater. The problem is, is that whenever the ship moves, water fills in that whole floor. I want an effective way to keep the water from filling in that floor, while still being able to use that floor. I would use signs, but it's timely, and doesn't look as good. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your design, and just how much below the water the floor is - you could try elevating it with a half block, and raising the ceiling by replacing full blocks with the top half of a half blocks.

Comment: Yeah, but when the ship moves, the whole floor goes underwater, so I would like a way to be able to navigate it clearly without it being underwater.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Make a complex command block loop that sets the water blocks to air?

Maybe you could make the lowest bit accessible of the boat still above water level, and the bit underwater just blocks.

I don't even know that plugin, but I hope this assists you some!

Hope this helps!